# AC analysis from a DC fresh grad/point of view

Tags: ac

So i was finished taking DC circuits and im adept at basic laws like KCL, KVL and Ohms. But today im taking AC circuits and i wondered why things dont work well as before. Lets take this  example

A series RL circuit is connected to a 110-V ac
source. If the voltage across the resistor is 85 V, ﬁnd
the voltage across the inductor.

So i solve it using phasors, using phytagoras for Vl, Vs and Vr, and I get the correct answer. Now when i try applying KVL around the loop, it doesnt give the correct answer (I just use KVL in a loop, Vs = Vr + Vl)

[image]

from the KVL perspective, everything in my equation seems valid, and so why it didn't end up the way phasors do?

PS: on the left part, youll see the phasors method, and right part is my so called KVL from DC circuits

Comment: What you're missing in the second approach is that \$I\$, \$V_R\$, and \$V_L\$ have unknown phases, even if the magnitude of \$V_R\$ is known. KVL still works, but you have to be consistent in your treatment of complex numbers.

Comment: so what does the 25V in Vl signifies? does it have any relevance at all?

Comment: +1, would you put these in the answer if its ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing in the second approach is that \$I\$, \$V_R\$, and \$V_L\$ have unknown phases, even if the magnitude of \$V_R\$ is known. KVL still works, but you have to be consistent in your treatment of complex numbers.

The 25V is an error. The magnitude of \$V_R\$ may be 85V, but its phase is not the same as the 110V input. The phase of the voltage across the resistor will lag that of the input, because the current through the inductor is lagging the voltage across it. As an extreme (non-physical) example, if the phase of \$V_R\$ were 180 degrees from the input voltage, the magnitude of \$V_L\$ would be 195 volts.

Comment: is the problem solvable without using phasors, like the classical method? (coz there are no angles given in the problem, no omegas and stuff)

Comment: Yes and no. I would work the problem algebraically in Cartesian complex numbers rather than polar form, but it's still the same idea. If you want to do it without complex numbers you need to solve it as a differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that AC voltages are RMS averages over time from which phase information has been removed, whereas Kirkhoff's Voltage Law asserts a fact about instantaneous voltages at a moment in time, and so has to be modified to work for AC voltages, and those voltages have to take into account phase (so they have to be vectors or complex numbers).

The problem *can* be solved without phasors if you switch to first principles and solve the differential equations governing the behavior (current and voltage relationship) of the capacitors, resistors and inductors to solve for the exact voltages and currents as functions of time.

Furthermore, the need to solve differential equations goes away if you transform to the Laplace domain (a.k.a. s-domain, because the commonly used domain variable in the Laplace domain is s). In s-domain analysis you can treat capacitances and inductances as if they were resistor-like impedances that can just be subject to naive voltage law calculations as if you were dealing with DC.

Intro video on Laplace circuit analysis: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0PZvvt36DA

Intro intro video on Laplace transform: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmDPbofx2Nk